# pfsense Multiple WAN DNS issue : when primary fails , the DNS systems stops

Tags: domain-name-system, pfsense, internal-dns, wide-area-network

I am using pfsense 2.2.6-RELEASE.  My configuration is as follows:

1. Two static WAN, One LAN
2. Using google and opendns
3. Configured WAN-Load balancing and WAN-Fail-over
4. Using aliases in firewall rules

When the primary WAN interface goes down, the DNS stops working.

There is fix available on pf-sense forum, but the forum is closed.  The link for forum posts is here https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=43982.0

Comment: The forum works for me and it looks like there is a solution in that thread.  Here is the reply post: https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=43982.msg249579#msg249579

Comment: You should not post the same question on multiple SE sites. Pick one and delete the others.

Comment: @RonMaupin Apologies and deleted from exchange.

Comment: @pato. , can you repost the it here.

Meanwhile I found one solution  on http://marc.info/?l=pfsense-discussion&m=137649712020774&w=2

Allow default gateway switching option must be enabled.
its is in  System -> Advanced -> Miscellaneous

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer found in [Re: Multiple WAN DNS issue when primary fails](https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=43982.msg249579#msg249579)

> Edit the default LAN rule in Firewall->Rules by clicking edit on the
>   rule that has a row that contains "LAN net". Then change Gateway
>   setting drop-down to whatever you named the gateway you created with
>   the Wan1 fallover to Wan2.
>
> Here is a link to a simple and basic working guide for multiwan setup
>   on pfSense 2.0. The top of the guide is for 1.2, but scroll about
>   half-way down to see the 2.0 guide:
>   http://skear.hubpages.com/hub/Dual-Wan-Router-How-To-Build-One-On-a-Budget.
>   Combine that info with the other guides out there for setting up
>   traffic shaping and it works great!